# Firewall allow all ports of w3wp.exe

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-firewall

I want to make the firwall take all process of my IIS 7.5 to allow inbound connections, becasue I dont wanna lost my time making each new application, and to do it easier to maintenance. Can I do it? Its a safe option? But when I allow the w3wp.exe, I dont have any response.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to allow inbound connections to IIS through your Windows firewall and it's not working?

Comment: If I allow one exactly port for example, port 999, my application of port 999 works fine! But if I delete this rule and add the rule to allow the w3wp.exe, my application has broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w3wp.exe is not the process that listens for incoming connections to IIS, it's a worker process that handles doing the work of a request once it's received.  Anyway, when you configure a rule to allow an image it's for outgoing connections.

In general you don't want to configure your firewall to accept inbound connections on wide ranges of ports.  It's not safe.  You should limit the inbound connections to those ports you know you need to accept and leave the rest closed.  Create inbound rules for the ports your web sites / apps are listening on.  Even better, you can configure IIS to listen on a single port and create multiple host bindings.  That way you only have to expose one port to incoming connections.

Comment: When allow all programs this work, if select some correct way I think works too but, your way works to thanks